# How to propagate setUp and tearDown across all tests in phpUnit?

Tags: phpunit

I have the following tests/ folder:

```
tests/
    ClassOne.test.php
    ClassTwo.test.php
    ClassThree.test.php
```

I am having to copy the following `setUp()` and `tearDown()` methods into each of these files:

```
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->dbTestData();
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        $this->dbClear();
    }

    private function dbTestData() {
        // populate the database with a few entries
        Entities\AutocompleteValue::create(array('field_name' => 'testing1', 'entry_value' => 'Aisforapple'));
        Entities\AutocompleteValue::create(array('field_name' => 'testing2', 'entry_value' => 'Bisforball'));
        Entities\AutocompleteValue::create(array('field_name' => 'testing3', 'entry_value' => 'Cisforcat'));
        Entities\AutocompleteValue::create(array('field_name' => 'testing4', 'entry_value' => 'Disfordog'));
    }

    private function dbClear() {
        DB::table('autocomplete_values')->delete();
    }
```

I have considered writing a single separate class which contains these methods, `require()` that file in each of the test files, and extend from *that* class instead of `PHPUnit_Framework_Testcase`. Is there an easier solution to this?

I do not have easy access to `phpunit.xml`, because my coding framework's CLI tool (Laravel, artisan) handles its creation. Hence, it would be better if there is a solution not involving that file.

Comment: Writing a base test class and extending from it is the best way to go, how is this not easy?

Comment: I did not like that I have to write a 'require' statement in every test file. I wanted to use Autoloading but my framework won't allow this. So looks like I'm stuck having to copy at least one line across all my test files.

Comment: Having a base test class is very common practice. You can eventually consider using composition if you want to go with a cleaner (but harder) way.

Comment: You can always use autoloading, I can't imagine any way to disallow that. You can stack autoloaders, so if the autoloaders of Laravel and PHPUnit do not serve you and you can't modify the PHPUnit bootstrap file, you still can add your own autoloader in the test suite.

Comment: Ocramius, do you think you could provide a laravel-compatible piece of code to help me with the Composition? To state concretely, Laravel doesn't start without me writing *some* sort of initialization (either `Bundle::start('name')` or something else, at the start of the file (this will start up the autoloader). This is not much different from having to use a require statement. I would love to eliminate this repetition altogether.

Comment: @fab, within a directory, is there any way I can hook into PHPUnit's `start` event? If I could, that would resolve my pain immediately. I could include said framework initialization code into this file. I only found docs about the bootstrap xml file and that one already is controlled by the framework.

Comment: I found that Laravel does allow me to add a few rules to the phpunit.xml file, and I've also just found this in the phpunit docs: `testSuiteLoaderClass="PHPUnit_Runner_StandardTestSuiteLoader"`; maybe there is some help in there, I will explore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give in and create the base class. That is the standard solution in this situation. It brings other advantages, such as a good place to keep the `static` assert extensions you create.

I'm struggling to even come up with an alternative approach, let alone one that is easier. All I can suggest is to use a script that scans each test file and inserts `setUp`, `tearDown` and their dependencies if they are not found. But (IMHO) that is a much more complex solution for no significant benefit.